# Signalr connection error messages

Tags: asp.net, websocket, signalr, signalr.client

I'm getting some reliably annoying messages when connecting to signalr.  The connection works (later?) but perhaps I'm doing something wrong.  Is there any reason why these messages are showing up?

On IE:

> SCRIPT12031: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12031, The connection with
>   the server was reset

Firefox:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   ws://localhost:54907/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=LW...cWu&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22qhub%22%7D%5D&tid=10.

**FIXED:**

I turned on the signalr tracing with `$.connection.hub.logging = true`.

Turns out that Signalr wasn't using Websockets at all and falling back to long polling ACK!  Some searching suggested that I was using the wrong targetFramework.  The following changes fixed the problem.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>-->
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your client environment is? When in your application lifecycle is this happening (on page load, or refresh)?

Comment: @RemedialBear Both;  on page load & when refreshing the page.